# How to use @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference for Many to Many relationship with best practice?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I will be much apprecaite for you to explain my questions.

I have 2 entity and 1 bridge table entity,

Let's say they are **Team, User and TeamUser.**

TeamEntity:

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "TEAM_ID")
    private Integer id;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "team", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<TeamUsers> team_users = new HashSet<>();
```

UserEntity:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@JsonBackReference
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
private Set<TeamUsers> team_users = new HashSet<>();
```

TeamUserEntity(bridge table):
@EmbeddedId
private TeamUsersId id;

```
@ManyToOne
@MapsId("teamId")
@JoinColumn(name = "team_id")
@JsonBackReference
private Team team;

@ManyToOne
@MapsId("userId")
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
@JsonManagedReference
private User user;

@Column(name = "active")
private int active;
```

As you can see I used ****@JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference****
***to telling the program the direction for the query of the Entity and avoid infinite recrusive.***

Now if I run get ***repo.findAll()*** on ***Team CRUDrepository*** I will get all Team object, and within the content I will get all bridge table data and it also include User details information.

But Let's say sometimes if I want to query the data in oppisite way, I want to get All User information and the object should contain all Team information, looks like the annotation ***@JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference*** block the result.

In real world development, how should we manage here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` annotations are used to handle circular references. They can be used to create a JSON structure in a bidirectional way. The `@JsonManagedReference` annotation is used on a child reference of the target POJO, which means it is a **forward reference** that includes during the serialization process whereas `@JsonBackReference` annotation is a **backreference** that omits during the serialization process, usually used in the corresponding child class.

Hence, The property annotated with `@JsonBackReference` here, which is the `Team` in the `TeamUsers`, won't be serialized. That is why when you try to get all the users having `Team` inside the `TeamUsers`, it won't work. Also, if it did, it would violate the purpose of the annotations that they're used for, recursive access mapping.

If you want to fetch data in either way, you  should use `@JsonIgnoreProperties` instead of those two annotations. Change your entity classes as follows and you'll get your desired output.

In `Team` class, set `@JsonIgnoreProperties("team")` on the `team_users` field to ignore mapping `team` inside this field again to avoid recursive mapping. Change your `Team` class to:

```
public class Team {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "TEAM_ID")
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "team", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("team")
    private Set<TeamUsers> team_users = new HashSet<>();

}
```

Similarly, in `User` class, set `@JsonIgnoreProperties("user")` on the `team_users` field to ignore mapping `user` inside this field again to avoid recursive mapping. Change your `User` class to:

```
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("user")
    private Set<TeamUsers> team_users = new HashSet<>();
}
```

And finally, in `TeamUsers` class, set `@JsonIgnoreProperties("team_users")` on both the `team` and `user` field to ignore mapping `team_users` inside these field again to avoid recursive mapping. Change your `TeamUsers` class to:

```
public class TeamUsers {

    @EmbeddedId
    private TeamUserId id;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("teamId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "team_id")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("team_users")
    private Team team;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("userId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("team_users")
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "active")
    private int active;
}
```

Now you can fetch the data in either way without having recursive mapping.

Comment: Thanks! Then what is the best approach if I want to query the result from User entity?
Let's say I want to get result from User ->bridge connection -> Team information,
it should be User Object and it contains team information.

Comment: I do have @ManyToOne in the bridge table and OneToMany in the individual entities.

Comment: @PEIRANLIU, I've updated my answer with your query. Please check now.